# How to reclassify records from two to four categories

Tags: python, algorithm, dataframe, subset

I have a pandas dataframe which contains product names [a, b, c, d, e, f, j, h, i, j, k, l] for millions of customers.
For each product, the data report whether the customer used the product (denotes by 1) or did not use (denotes by 0) during the current month.

The origional classification of customers: 1 for use and 0 for non-use
I would like to reclassify the product use into four categories:

S: used
   M: maintained use(used in several subsequent months)
   N: not used
   D: Maintained non-used(not used for several consecutive months)

The origional data looks like the following:

```
+-------------+-------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| Customer_ID | Month | a | b | c | d | e | f | j | h | i | j | k | l |
+-------------+-------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 19509       | Jan   | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19509       | Feb   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 19509       | Mar   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19509       | Apr   | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19509       | May   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19509       | Jun   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19509       | Jul   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19509       | Aug   | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19509       | Sep   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19510       | Jan   | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19510       | Feb   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 19510       | Mar   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19510       | Apr   | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19510       | May   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19510       | Jun   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19510       | Jul   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19510       | Aug   | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19510       | Sep   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19511       | Jan   | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19511       | Feb   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 19511       | Mar   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19511       | Apr   | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19511       | May   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19511       | Jun   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19511       | Jul   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 19511       | Aug   | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19511       | Sep   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
+-------------+-------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I would like to reclassify the customers into four categories to take into account those who maintained use or maintained non-use for several months.

The result should look like the following:

```
+-------------+-------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| Customer_ID | Month | a | b | c | d | e | f | j | h | i | j | k | l |
+-------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 19509       | Jan   | S | N | S | N | N | S | N | S | N | S | S | N |
| 19509       | Feb   | M | N | N | D | D | M | D | M | D | N | M | D |
| 19509       | Mar   | M | S | S | D | D | M | D | M | D | S | M | D |
| 19509       | Apr   | N | M | N | S | D | M | D | M | D | N | N | D |
| 19509       | May   | D | N | D | M | S | M | D | M | D | D | D | D |
| 19509       | Jun   | D | D | D | M | N | M | D | M | D | D | D | D |
| 19509       | Jul   | S | S | S | N | D | M | D | M | D | S | S | D |
| 19509       | Aug   | N | M | N | D | D | M | D | N | D | N | N | D |
| 19509       | Sep   | S | M | S | S | D | M | D | D | S | S | S | D |
| 19510       | Jan   | S | N | S | N | N | S | N | S | N | S | S | N |
| 19510       | Feb   | M | N | N | D | D | M | D | M | D | N | M | D |
| 19510       | Mar   | M | S | S | D | D | M | D | M | D | S | M | D |
| 19510       | Apr   | N | M | N | S | D | M | D | M | D | N | N | D |
| 19510       | May   | D | N | D | M | S | M | D | M | D | D | D | D |
| 19510       | Jun   | D | D | D | M | N | M | D | M | D | D | D | D |
| 19510       | Jul   | S | S | S | N | D | M | D | M | D | S | S | D |
| 19510       | Aug   | N | M | N | D | D | M | D | N | D | N | N | D |
| 19510       | Sep   | S | M | S | S | D | M | D | D | S | S | S | D |
| 19511       | Jan   | S | N | S | N | N | S | N | S | N | S | S | N |
| 19511       | Feb   | M | N | N | D | D | M | D | M | D | N | M | D |
| 19511       | Mar   | M | S | S | D | D | M | D | M | D | S | M | D |
| 19511       | Apr   | N | M | N | S | D | M | D | M | D | N | N | D |
| 19511       | May   | D | N | D | M | S | M | D | M | D | D | D | D |
| 19511       | Jun   | D | D | D | M | N | M | D | M | D | D | D | D |
| 19511       | Jul   | S | S | S | N | D | M | D | M | D | S | S | D |
| 19511       | Aug   | N | M | N | D | D | M | D | N | D | N | N | D |
| 19511       | Sep   | S | M | S | S | D | M | D | D | S | S | S | D |
+-------------+-------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The algorithm to do it seems complicated and I am still thinking about the appropriate sequence to do it.

I would like to do it for all customers and for all products(columns) and I think we can start like this:

```
for i in customer_ID:
  for j in df.columns:
```

Note: This case is not use and nonuse case, rather it is join(1), cancel(0), keep idle(0) and if again joined(1) and so on. So when it is zero, it means the customer cancelled the service and when it is zero in the next three months, means he is not a customer and then he joined and once more he cancelled, we should know how many times he cancelled the service. If we just calculate the total, it will not give us how many times the customer has joined and how many times he cancelled a particular product or service.

I appreciate any advice or idea to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity reasons I explain how to do it for one customer and one product you can just do it for each customer and column then:

1. Find the earliest entry  (If you do this in November, then you can start by looking for values in Dec, Jan, Feb and so on until you find one) and apply new values:

   - 0 => N
   - 1 => S
2. For the next (up to 11) entries you apply values based on the previous value and what's in the column denoted as `f(old, val)` here:

   - f(N,0) => D
   - f(N,1) => S
   - f(S,0) => N
   - f(S,1) => M
   - f(M,0) => N
   - f(M,1) => M
   - f(D,0) => D
   - f(D,1) => S

In this case this could be simplified (N/D and S/M yield the same result, it would be sufficient to look at the previous value instead of the previous state), but if you have more complex state transitions then it maybe cannot, so I wrote it out to show the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

[Prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum):

- if ever increasing - use
- if increase slugish is over periods but, come Dec, the total sum is over threshold - maintained use

You can figure the rest.

[Kadane's algoritm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) - maximum subarray - if you mark +1 for use, -1 for not used, this one will tell you the maximum length of the period in which the use is prevalent over non-use.

Comment: Actually it is not use and nonuse case, because when it is zero, it means the customer cancelled the service and when it is zero in the next three months, and then he joined and once more he cancelled, we should know how many times he cancelled the service. If we just calculate the total, it will not give us how many times the customer has joined and how many times he cancelled a particular product or service.